# Wrong image used by skaffold in deployment

Tags: skaffold

Here is my `skaffold.yaml`

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta12
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: myimage
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: myimage
    docker:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
    - k8s/deployment_auth.yaml
```

And here is `k8s/deployment_auth.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myimage
        image: myimage:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

When I execute `skaffold dev`, I get

```
Starting deploy...
 - deployment.apps/myapp created
Waiting for deployments to stabilize...myimage
    - pod/myimage-5f74748bd6-ghvzh: creating container myimage
 - deployment/myapp: container myimage is waiting to start: myimage:0127e9fb7b7b5bf9971f53c313c1c5c1877903ca5c194b5c315234cbf15191dc can't be pulled
    - pod/myimage-5f74748bd6-ghvzh: container myimage is waiting to start: myimage:0127e9fb7b7b5bf9971f53c313c1c5c1877903ca5c194b5c315234cbf15191dc can't be pulled
 - deployment/myapp failed. Error: container myimage is waiting to start: myimage:0127e9fb7b7b5bf9971f53c313c1c5c1877903ca5c194b5c315234cbf15191dc can't be pulled.
```

Why is that?

Where does `skaffold` come up with the `image:hash` pattern with?

Answer (score 0):

Skaffold replaces image references with the built image, but the references must match exactly what is shown in the `skaffold.yaml`.  Alter your deployment to:

```yaml
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myimage
        image: myimage         # must match corresponding build.artifacts.image in skaffold.yaml
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```